# How to apply conditional formating to a list of strings?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet full of strings, columns A:AH
There are 16 different options for the cells to equal.
I want to color them in groups of 4

So say,

```
=or(match("Apples",A:AH),match("Bananas",A:AH),match("Pears",A:AH),match("Plums",A:AH))
```

except that doesn't work. I can always go in and add 16 text equals conditionals, just trying to find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(OR(A1="apples", 
       A1="bananas", 
       A1="pear", 
       A1="plumb"), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Eureka! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using `REGEXMATCH` is another option.

Apply the custom formula condition below to the range `A:AH`.

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1,"(?i)^(apples|bananas|pear|plumb)$")
```

---

#### Code explanation

`(?i)` this adds the ignore-case flag: match Apples, apples, APPLES, apPPles, etc

`|` The pipe means **OR**

The two symbols below ensure that the cell contains ONLY the specified string.

`^` Beginning of the string

`$` End of the string

---

#### Plain English explanation

- Ignore the case
- Start at the beginning
- Find apples, bananas, pear, or plumb
- Make sure the end of the string is next
- Returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`

---

Check out [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) for a great testing tool.